# XCode - Convert array element to string

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, nsmutablearray

I'm trying to get the elements of an `NSMutableArray`, convert them to strings which are names of `UIImageViews` and change all the images to one image. I'm using this `for` loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < [self.array count]; i++)
    NSString *currentelement = [self.array objectAtIndex:i]
    [UIImageView * theImageView = [self valueForKey:currentelement]
    [theImageView setImage:newimage];
```

but it gives me an error on the second line: **Expected expression**  Any Ideas why?

Comment: What you have in your self.array ? Are they string names of your imagesviews ?

Comment: You have forgotton the semi colons to end C statements and do you really want to loop just over the second line - I think you have forgottem the {} - Hint alwys use braces for all loops

Comment: Yes, it's a mutable array which has strings already in it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing some basic C punctuation. You have forgotton the semi colons to end C statements and do you really want to loop just over the second line - I think you have forgotten the {} - Hint alwys use braces for all loops.

So Code would be like

```
for (int i = 0; i < [self.array count]; i++)
{
    NSString *currentelement = [self.array objectAtIndex:i];
    UIImageView * theImageView = [self valueForKey:currentelement];
    [theImageView setImage:newimage];
}
```

Also [ are used for messages and should only appear on the right hand side of an assignement (`=`)

I would suggest you need to look at some C and Objective C tutorials to show correct code and describe the syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the semicolons and the third line is wrong:

Change your code to:

```
for (int i = 0; i < [self.array count]; i++) {
    NSString *currentelement = [self.array objectAtIndex:i];
    UIImageView *theImageView = [self valueForKey:currentelement];
    [theImageView setImage:newimage];
}
```

Using `[]` means we send a message to an object. We cannot use the `=` sign in a message.

Comment: @ the downvoter: Can you please explain what's wrong with my answer so that I can update it? Thanks!